# Play returning route not found page when route is valid

Tags: routes, playframework, content-type

Sometimes my play app spits back the "route not found and all the routes below were tried" page.

The route that's being tried is valid though and is specified in my routes file.

Hitting reload on my browser thus initiating a second request resolves the issue.

I can hit reload on my browser 100 times for a given page and a few times I'll get the route not found screen. This is not a load balancing issue as I'm hitting a single server directly.

This is impacting customers in prod. We can tell them to "just reload if that happens", but I'm not happy with that. it makes us look bad. This is on play 1.2.3. any help is appreciated.

Also to bundle in another question, when this happens, the routes not found page doesn't get rendered, it comes to the client as html source and their client browser displays the source instead of rendering it as HTML.

/shakes fist at Play

Thanks
Josh

Comment: Did some sleuthing, and it turns out the "route not found" page is actually the 404 error page. I looked at the 404 page and realized it's content type is being set dynamically, (which is not the case with all my other screens). So I changed it from ${_response_encoding} to just be hardcoded to UTF-8 like all my other html templates. Soooo, I'm praying that explains why when the 404 page was sent to clients their browser didn't know what content type it was. But this still doesn't answer the question of why people are getting the 404 page so often for valid routes.

Comment: try to add a log4j.properties which log every debug info. there are many info for com.ning.http

Comment: And is that the same when you use siege or just a looping curl to test?